# In finite $n$-dimensional vector space, a collection of $n$ vectors that spans a dense subset of the space, is it a basis?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider a $n$-dim real vector space $A$ (say $\mathbb{R}^n$), and there exists a collection of $n$ vectors $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ such that it spans a dense subset of $A$.

I am wondering if this collection of vectors forms a basis of $A$?
(It seems it is true, but I cannot prove it)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your conjecture is obviously true: in $\Bbb R^n$ with its usual topology, every subspace is closed.

Comment: Oh, yes!! That really helps! Thanks @AnneBauval

Comment: @sam: You will have to prove, though, that every subspace is closed - and this is equivalent to your question. So, how do you prove it?

Comment: [Show that finite dimensional subspace is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764798), [Show that if X is a normed linear space, then any finite-dimensional subspace M of X must be closed.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925875)

Answer (score 2):

Really thanks @Guillermo García Sáez for pointing out the topology and @AnneBauval for providing answer!

It is indeed a basis since "in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with its usual topology, any subspace is closed".

$span\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is a subspace and it is dense, so it in fact is the whole space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

===== Proof of the quoted statement =====

Suppose there is a subspace $S$ that is not closed, that means there exists a converging sequence of vectors in $S$ but the limit is not in $S$, i.e.,
$$\{u_k\}\subset S\to u, u\not\in S.$$
Since $S$ is a subspace (say $dim(S)=m\leq n$), we can write down the basis $\{b_1,...b_m\}$. Also note $u$ is linearly independent to $\{b_1,...b_m\}$, then $\{b_1,...b_m,u\}$ is linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Consider the subspace $S^*$ spanned by $\{b_1,...b_m,u\}$, and reconsider the above converging sequence $\{u_k\}\subset S^*$. Under the basis $\{b_1,...b_m,u\}$,
$$u_k=(u_{k1},...,u_{km},0),$$
while,
$$u=(0,...0,1).$$
Since $u_k\to u$, we have $u_{ki}\to0$ and $0\to1$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Alternatively, every subspace is the nullspace of some linear map, and linear maps in finite dimension are continuous.